# Social login in safe web wallet

Tags: gnosis-safe

I noticed a couple of branches (tkeympc and web3auth-test) in the safe web wallet repo with implementations of social login using web3auth, is there a reason for not using the `web3-onboard/web3auth` module? It seems like a much simpler approach than what is currently being implemented.

Comment: As this is a question about particular design choices made by software developers, I suggest you ask them directly. Members of the public forum do not have telepathy and cannot read the mind of the developers who work on this software.

Comment: Makes sense, thx